# Array Type Declaration C#

Tags: c#

I'm declaring an array of 16bit signed integers whose elements may run into the millions. I've been declaring the array as type Long as I was thinking along the terms of element length instead of the limit of each individual element. Is it correct to declare the type of array according to element types?

Thanks

Comment: If all you need is 16 bits, why use a 64 bit value type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The element type of an array has nothing to do with the type of the index.
C# arrays only support 32-bit `int` indexing.

You should use a `short[]`.

Comment: Ok, so if the number of elements exceeds 2^32, will I then get an overflow err?

Comment: @Mickey It sounds like arrays are not the tool you need.